# How to group by and order correctly

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a problem ordering my results correctly when using the group by. It seems to show the first entry in the database instead of the most recent in the group.

Example:

> id(autoincrement) | name
>  
>   1                 | anne
>   2                 | james
>   3                 | anne
>   4                 | brad

As you can see I have "anne" entered multiple times which is why I am using the group by. I would then like it to display the "anne" that is the most recent, which would be the entry "3". Instead it displays the first "anne"(1)

My query

> "Select * FROM **TABLE** GROUP BY name ORDER BY id DESC

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're selecting all the fields (using * is seldom a good idea) so each row is unique therefore there is nothing to group on.

Try:

```
SELECT 
  Name,
  MAX(ID)
FROM
  TABLE
GROUP BY
  Name
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM TABLE
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE GROUP BY name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this; it will work:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
                FROM TABLE
                group by name)
    ids ON TABLE.id = ids.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on another anwer already provided, this SQL will avoid having to GROUP BY Name:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT Name,
  MAX(ID)
FROM
  TABLE
```